# Ionic framework, pass var to view from construct?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I call in my app in `construct()` a external json, in console log I see correct result of:

```
var url = 'https://my_path.co/apiv1/products';

this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(items => console.log(items));
```

I tried like:

```
this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(items => items);

and 

this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(items => {items => items});
```

With `*ngFor` I don't get any resulsts, also if I create in construct a string I cannot get it in view like `{{my_string}}`

How can I pass my json result to view to list all elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show the results in the view, you need to declare a property in the component, and assign what you want to show in the view, to  that property:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  public items: any; // This creates a public property (accessible from the view), called items, whose type is any (could assign anything to it).
  public myString: string;

  // It's better to avoid making http calls in the constructor, we should use ionViewWillLoad / ionViewWillEnter or any other life cycle hood
  constructor() {}

  ionViewWillLoad() {
    let url = 'https://my_path.co/apiv1/products';

    this.myString = 'Demo app!';

    this.http.get(url)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(itemsFromServer => {

        // Here you can assign the result (itemsFromServer) to the property from the component (would be this.items)
        this.items = itemsFromServer;
        console.log(this.items)

      });
    }

}
```

Now you can use the `items` and the `myString` properties in your view, like this:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar color="primary">
        <ion-title>{{ myString }}</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
      {{ item | json }}
    </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```